# React Native - document is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am porting a mobile app from Cordova to React Native. The Cordova app depends on a 3rd party JavaScript library [Kandy.Io](https://developer.kandy.io/docs/javascript/2-7)

This library makes use of the global `document` object. When I import that library into my React Native project, I see the error :

```
document is not defined
```

I understand that there is no DOM like in a browser environment, but is there any way to use the document object in a React Native project so that I can continue using this library?

Comment: Depends on the context — there's no "document object" in React Native for the reason you've stated (no DOM), so depending on how you're using the document object would affect how you can rewrite your code to account for there being no document.

Comment: Looks like if you want to do "DOM" style manipulation you'll need to edit the `setNativeProps` property via [Direct Manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)

Comment: sounds like you need to check to see if there is an isomorphic version of that library available (a tip: good idea to mention the actual library, in case people already ran into this problem before, so they can help you)

Comment: @NickZuber Can you point me in a good direction to write a shim for an existing library? I can't seem to find any resources on that

Comment: Maby this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336676/getelementbyid-react-native

Comment: I am also currently having this problem after I remove the node modules and installed it again . .

Answer (score 1):

I had the 'document is not defined' when using react native webgl with threejs.

Short summary: the Textureloader didnt work because it required an imageloader which required the inaccesible DOM.

Apparantly there's a THREE.Texture function which i used like this:

```
let texture = new THREE.Texture(
     url //URL = a base 64 JPEG string in this case     
     );

var img = new Image(128, 128);
img.src = url;
texture.normal = img;
```

As you can see i used an Image constructor, this is from React Native and is imported like this:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
```

In the  [react native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) it will explain how it can be used, it supports base64 encoded JPEG.

You could try a similar approach in your case, so what you should do is look which function uses the document and either override that function or work around it with something react native offers