# How to disable one button when another button is pressed in react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

In react-native-paper (or even in react-native dirctly) I don't understand how to do the equivalent of getElementById to modify an element. In JavaScript, I would assign each button a unique id, and then when one button is clicked, I can call function that will disable/enable the other button based on its id.

However I am not seeing how to accomplish this task in react-native-paper (or react-native either).

Here is sample code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View>
      <Button mode="contained" color="green" onPress={() => this.buttonOnePressed()}>Button One</Button>
      <Button mode="contained" color="red" onPress={() => this.buttonTwoPressed()}>Button Two</Button>
    </View>
    );
  }

  buttonOnePressed() {
    // If Button Two is disabled, then enable it.
    // If Button Two is enabled, then disable it.
    Alert.alert('Button ONE pressed');
  }

  buttonTwoPressed() {
    // Do something when Button Two is pressed
    Alert.alert('Button TWO pressed');
  }

}
```

Comment: this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336676/getelementbyid-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code make a state for the 1st button and another state for the 2nd button. Then by handling the state of the 2, you can achieve what you want

Here's a sample code:

```
export class default Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstButtonEnable: false,
            secondButtonDisable: false,
        }
        this.handlingButton = this.handlingButton.bind(this)
    }

    handlingButton(){
        firstButtonEnable
        ?  this.setState({secondButtonDisable: true})
        : null;
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Button title='Button1' onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({firstButtonEnable: true});
                    handlingButton();
                }} />
                <Button disabled={secondButtonDisable} title='Button2' } />
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```