# Switch javascript vanilla into React native JS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I did this function in js vanilla but now i'm working with react native. Someone can help me to switch this code on react native js please ? Thank's in advance

```
TimerDecibels = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs.map((element) => {
      // Set the date we're counting down to
      var countDownDate = new Date(element.dateStopMatch).getTime();

      // Update the count down every 1 second
      var x = setInterval(function () {
        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date(element.dateMatch).getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor(
          (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60),
        );
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
          days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's ';

        // If the count down is over, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
          clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Isn't React Native also in JS. Shouldn't most Vanilla JS code work just fine in React Native exactly the same? I'm no expert with react though so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JonahCRowlinson [React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native) is a Javascript library. There should be no difference.

Comment: @JonahCRowlinson There is no `document.getElementById` is React Native.

Comment: @Titus ah ok, didn't know what.

Comment: it's what i thought but document.getElementByID seems not working  to render the countdown :/

Comment: @jonahCRowlinson, how i can replace it ?

Comment: what do you expect to have? with your function?

Comment: Only a couple things I could find: [StackOverflow Question seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336676/getelementbyid-react-native) and [Regular React Article seems like it could be useful](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)